# How to get product count for anchor category?

Tags: php, magento

This code works only for non anchor categories - how can I get the product count of anchor category?

```
<div class="grid_16"><h1 class="highlight pageTitle"><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?>

        <span>
            (<?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>)
        </span>

    </h1></div>
```

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/200940/#t270248

Comment: check document, there is a method which is count anchor and nonanchor [http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Collection.html]

Answer (score 5):

```
$prodCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addCategoryFilter($category); 

var_dump($prodCollection->count());
```

Comment: Hello, this work fine tk, just a problem, the count include disabled products, how i can remove this?

Comment: Need  add filter like - status

Comment: Need  add filter, like - status. But if  you  want  use Resourse model, this is very bad  solution, becouse will very depend  with speed of Magento. Use only Models!

Answer (score 2):

As seen here : [magento forum](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/44262/#t217659)

```
$category_object = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load( CATEGORY_ID ); // If you don't already have one
$total = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->setCurrentCategory( $category_object )->getProductCollection()->getSize()
```

Will show correct number of products